# Getting variable value out of for loop

Tags: javascript

I am currently using a for loop in javascript to iterate over an array.
Its working fine, but I can still get the variable value used in for loop outside the loop. I am not able to find the cause.
Here is the code snippet.

```
var list = ['delhi','mumbai','pune','kolkata'];
for (let i = 0, max = list.length ; i < max ; i++ ){
  var current_city =  list[i];
  //other code goes here
}
console.log(current_city);
```

It's printing 'kolkata' outside the for loop.

Comment: You want to print all cities in the loop ?

Comment: Knowing what you're trying to do with current_city goes a long way toward giving you a better answer :)

Comment: I dont want to print all the cities in loop. I am using them inside for loop. but i can print the current_city variable outside the for loop, which is strange to me. I just want to know why this is happening.

Comment: The behaviour is correct. For variable scoping u can refer this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types

Comment: Note that if you use `let current_city = list[i];` (instead of `var`), then `current_city` will *not* be hoisted. It would be unavailable (and, I believe, throw a ReferenceError) outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set `var current_city` to `let current_city` . . .

```
var list = ['delhi','mumbai','pune','kolkata'];
for (let i = 0, max = list.length ; i < max ; i++ ){
    let current_city =  list[i];
    //other code goes here
}
console.log(current_city); // shows error, as you expect.
```

Answer (score 1):

That behavior is correct.  You keep reassigning the value of `current_city` so it just logs the last one.  If you want them all logged, just move the `console.log` inside the loop.

```
var list = ['delhi','mumbai','pune','kolkata'];
for (let i = 0, max = list.length ; i < max ; i++ ){
  var current_city =  list[i];
console.log(current_city);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't have block scope, just function scope. Since the initialization of `current_city` is within one function, that variable is accessible anywhere else in that same function. These variables are not local to the loop, i.e. they are in the same scope the for loop is in.

You keep reassigning the value of `current_city` so it is assigned the last item from the array when the loop ends. Hence you get the result `kolkata`